# With AWS API Gateway and Lambda, i'm seeing the paths all prefixed with $default

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm using AWS API Gateway and Lambda

Configuration is as follows:

API Gateway: Protocol is HTTP, route is '$default', integration is to my lambda function, payload format is 1.0, and permissions are correctly configured, stage name is $default. Everything else is vanilla.

Lambda: Runtime is 'custom runtime' (not linux 2), with an executable called 'bootstrap'. It's actually written in Rust using Rocket + rocket_lamb but that shouldn't make much difference.

What i'm finding is that when you browse to the API Gateway Invoke URL, the lambda is called with path = '$default/' instead of '/' - eg it literally includes '$default'.

Am i missing something here? Where is this $default coming from? I thought using '$default' in the route was the wildcard?

Thanks

Comment: `$default` is default stage that is created, we can change the stage name to qa, prod etc. instead of $default,  We can also create a custom domain pointing to a api gateway + stage suffix, then we don't have to use stage at all

Comment: Thankyou @BaluVyamajala :) I'm not sure what you mean however. You say 'we dont have to use stage at all' so I removed the stage, however then there's no Invoke URL to try.

Comment: What you are `Routes`? Also it only happens for your custom lambda, or any lambda function?

Comment: @Marcin There is one route, '$default' with the lambda integration. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you maybe add some screenshots of your setup. This could help to reproduce your setup and locale where does the literal string `$default` comes from.

Comment: Excluding stage name from paths on rust - [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77925481/2455388)

Answer (score 1):

Stages help keep different versions of api active, typically used to maintain multiple environments. we can have stages like dev, qa, prod, etc.

Any changes we make to API will not be effective until we deploy to a particular stage.(unless auto-deploy is enabled)

Finally the route will be

`https://${apidId}.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/${stage}/${route}`

Example 1: For /staff route, $default stage , abcdefgh api

`https://abcdefgh.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/staff`

Example 2: for /staff route, dev stage , abcdefgh api

`https://abcdefgh.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/staff`

Example 3: for / route, $default stage , abcdefgh api
`https://abcdefgh.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/`

So, the $default path you are using in lambda function is because you are using $default stage.

For HTTP Api ,
When defining a new api, we can set the stage, which by default is `$default`

[image]

or we can add stages after it is created.

[image]

Comment: So i'm just doing an HTTP request to root at `https://abcdefg.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/` without specifying the stage or route, yet something is coming through to the lambda. Am i silly to try to use API gateway for a web frontend, is it only realistic to use it for apis where you can have a prefix?

Comment: No. you are good. if you don't attach the stage, it will be $default, and if we don't add any child routes but add a lambda integration to a method under root '/', then requests from api gateway url with no suffix will be redirected to Lambda. when you say web frontend, do you mean a static single page website?

Comment: Ok so it's redirecting to lambda just fine, it's just that it adds '$default' to the path that it passes to the lambda function. By web frontend, i mean a Rocket app (kinda like rails really - eg it takes all sorts of routes and handles them, REST style but with HTML in a sense).

Answer (score 0):

So I think i have resolved this... i created a very simply nodejs lambda with the following code and changed my api gateway to point to it:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(event),
  };
  return response;
};
```

And from this, I was able to inspect what API gateway was actually passing to the lambda. And from what i can see, it isn't sending $default in any paths. So my conclusion is that rocket_lamb (or rocket) is concatenating fields that it shouldn't be, unfortunately coming up with URLs that look like `$default/foo/bar`. Apologies for the wild goose chase all.